# sqllocaldb gives random pipe connection string everytime starts up

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, localdb

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 and Visual Studio 2013. By default, EF produces "MSSqlLocaldb" as data source in app.config. In development, from time to time I have to run SQL query on the entity tables manually to check. I notice that I have to manual run console cmd "sqllocaldb start MSSqlLocaldb", then "sqllocaldb info MSSqlLocaldb" to get the np string to connect to, and every time the string is different.

Is there easy way to work around this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the string, and what is different to save us reproducing.

Answer (score 1):

Just share the instance and the pipe will remain static.